# Hide breadcrumb bar at bottom of HTML editor

Tags: html, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 with Web Essentials and Resharper 9.  When I'm editing an HTML file, I see this at the very bottom of my editor:

[image: bar]

At the very bottom, you see the ticker?  How do I hide that?  I never use it and would like to free up some space in my editor window.

Edit: This is what I have available in Options.  "Enable Tag Navigator" is not available:

[image: foo]

Answer (score 0):

That bar is a `Tag Navigator` for quick access to parts of a HTML code , if you don't want this
**Tools >> Option >> Text Editor >> HTML >> Advanced** and disable Tag Navigator

[image]

Comment: in option windows search bar for same object @Amy

Comment: What?  I don't understand.

Comment: There is a search bar at the Top left of your 'option windows'..... Search for' tag navigator' @amy